# factory_bot_rails stubbed models are not allowed to access the database ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am not that experienced in writing tests so apologize in advance if the question is not accurate enough, so I was writing some specs and suddenly started to receive `stubbed models are not allowed to access the database`, I realized that is due to a flow on a particular spec, something like `book.update_column(:title, 'El principito')`, so I looked around and seems like factory_bot_rails does not stub the response from `update_column`, the thing is that I need to use `update_column` because I don't want to trigger callbacks on this flow, any ideas on how to accomplish this?

(I manage to change a little the flow in order to be able to run the specs successfully but I don't like that approach)

My stack: rails 5.2.3, ruby 2.6.3, RSpec

Thx in advance !

Comment: to improve your test writing skill read https://www.betterspecs.org/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a object using Factory bot you need to use create in factories. Example:

```
FactoryBot.create(:book)
```

If you are creating with build_stubbed you will get this error.

```
FactoryBot.build_stubbed(:book)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have used the `build_stubbed` method to build an instance of the model.
so if you want to update it and don't want to save do it like this.

```
book.title = 'El principito'
```

And if you want to use `update, save or update_column` method then record must be persisted in the database. In this case instead of stubbing,  create book record using the `create` method

`create(:book, title: 'ABC')`
And now you can use `update, save and update-column methods`